# Blank screen after install gnome

Tags: 16.04, gnome, gnome-shell

I have installed [gnome desktop](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/05/install-gnome-3-20-ubuntu-16-04-lts) on Ubuntu 16.04. when I restarted, I get a blank screen after boot. 
If anyone has overcome this issue.